# pop-up dialog in mvc 4 Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dialog

I have dropdown list for select Destination in _ChooseGenre.cshtml view file
      @Html.DropDownList("DestinationID", ViewBag.Destination as SelectList, String.Empty)

I want add short cut to enable user to add new Destination  that  why i add link for /Destination/Create page

```
<a class="button" href="@Url.Content("~/Destination/Create")" id="DestinationAddLink">Add New Destination</a>
```

creates a hidden div, with the ID of DestinationDialog. We will use jQuery to hook up our Add Genre dialog box with the ID DestinationDialog in this div.

```
<div id="DestinationDialog" class="hidden">
</div>
```

javascript file for chooseDestination.js responsiple uses the ID DestinationDialog to create a dialog box on the div tag in the  Views\StoreManager_ChooseGenre.cshtml

create a dialog box on the div tag in the  Views\StoreManager_ChoosDestination.cshtml
The following code in the Scripts\chooseDestinatio.js  file shows the how the Add New Destinatio button gets connected to the click event, and how the Add New Destinatio dialog box is created.

```
$(function () {
    $('#DestinationDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Add Destination',
        buttons: {
            'Save': function () {
                var createDestinationForm = $('#createDestinationForm');
                if (createDestinationForm.valid()) {
                    $.post(createDestinationForm.attr('action'), createDestinationForm.serialize(), function (data) {
                        if (data.Error != '') {
                            alert(data.Error);
                        }
                        else {
                            // Add the new Destination to the dropdown list and select it
                            $('#DestinationId').append(
                                    $('<option></option>')
                                        .val(data.Destination.DestinationId)
                                        .html(data.Destination.DestinationName)
                                        .prop('selected', true)  // Selects the new Destination in the DropDown LB
                                );
                            $('#DestinationDialog').dialog('close');
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            'Cancel': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    $('#DestinationAddLink').click(function () {
        var createFormUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#DestinationDialog').html('')
        .load(createFormUrl, function () {
            // The createDestinationForm is loaded on the fly using jQuery load. 
            // In order to have client validation working it is necessary to tell the 
            // jQuery.validator to parse the newly added content
            jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#createDestinationForm');
            $('#DestinationDialog').dialog('open');
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

*when i run i get error from browse google chrome jquery debugger*

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui-1.10.3.js:314
>   Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog' chooseDestination.js:2

***notice*** i refer for jscript file

```
<link href="@Url.Content("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css")" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js")" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js")" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but you should put `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be facing Jquery Conflict, Try this :-

```
var jq = jQuery.noCOnflict();

jq('#DestinationAddLink').click(function () {
    var createFormUrl = jq(this).attr('href');
    jq('#DestinationDialog').html('')
    .load(createFormUrl, function () {
        // The createDestinationForm is loaded on the fly using jQuery load. 
        // In order to have client validation working it is necessary to tell the 
        // jQuery.validator to parse the newly added content
        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#createDestinationForm');
        jq('#DestinationDialog').dialog('open');
    });

return false;
});
```